# EQMX not started as a service

Tags: mqtt, emq

Fedora 31.

EMQX does not start as a service.
It starts successfully from the console.

```
=====
===== LOGGING STARTED Wed Apr  8 13:12:55 +05 2020
=====
Exec: /usr/lib/emqx/erts-10.5/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/lib/emqx/releases/v4.0.5/emqx -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /usr/lib/emqx/erts-10.5/../lib -mnesia dir "/var/lib/emqx/mnesia/emqx@127.0.0.1" -config /var/lib/emqx/configs/app.2020.04.08.13.12.56.config -args_file /var/lib/emqx/configs/vm.2020.04.08.13.12.56.args -vm_args /var/lib/emqx/configs/vm.2020.04.08.13.12.56.args -start_epmd false -epmd_module ekka_epmd -proto_dist ekka -- console
Root: /usr/lib/emqx
/usr/lib/emqx
Starting emqx on node emqx@127.0.0.1
Start http:management listener on 8081 successfully.
Start http:dashboard listener on 18083 successfully.
Start mqtt:tcp listener on 0.0.0.0:11883 successfully.
Start mqtt:tcp listener on 0.0.0.0:1883 successfully.
Start mqtt:ssl listener on 0.0.0.0:8883 successfully.
EMQ X Broker 4.0.5 is running now!
Eshell V10.5  (abort with ^G)
(emqx@127.0.0.1)1> Stop mqtt:tcp listener on 0.0.0.0:11883 successfully.
(emqx@127.0.0.1)1> Stop mqtt:tcp listener on 0.0.0.0:1883 successfully.
(emqx@127.0.0.1)1> Stop mqtt:ssl listener on 0.0.0.0:8883 successfully.
(emqx@127.0.0.1)1> [os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maby your TCP port 8083 already in use, please check it

```
Starting emqx on node emqx@127.0.0.1
Start http:management listener on 8081 successfully.
Start http:dashboard listener on 18083 successfully.
Start mqtt:tcp listener on 127.0.0.1:11883 successfully.
Start mqtt:tcp listener on 0.0.0.0:1883 successfully.
Start mqtt:ws listener on 0.0.0.0:8083 successfully.
Start mqtt:ssl listener on 0.0.0.0:8883 successfully.
Start mqtt:wss listener on 0.0.0.0:8084 successfully.
EMQ X Broker 4.1.0-alpha.2 is running now!
Eshell V10.6.1  (abort with ^G)
(emqx@127.0.0.1)1>
```

Comment: the specified port is not used - I checked